# GO permissions issue for Visual Studio Code (MAC OS Big Sur 11.3.1)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, terminal, authorization

I was wondering if you could help me with this issue I've really been struggling with recently.

I have recently installed Visual Studio Code and GO in order to work on a few projects and I have run into this error when attempting to download the GO extensions for my IDE;

```
Installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@latest FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go install -v 
github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: could not create module cache: mkdir /Users/go: 
permission denied\n"
}
```

Every single attempt to install a GO related file on my IDE has been met with a permissions denial.

Comment: What is the value of $GOPATH? (maybe try "echo $GOPATH" in terminal)

Comment: Hi there and thank you for getting back to me. I solved this issue locally by moving my go folder from usr/src/local/bin to my root inside my finder. Whilst I'm still not sure why this issue happened, pointing my go path at usr/src/local/bin didn't work but moving it and pointing it to my default file path under my user did.

Answer (score 4):

sudo chown -R your_name:admin $((go env GOROOT))